# Xamarin IOS Error Native linking failed when Build

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I run Project from visual studio 2022 on windows, when run on simulator run well but when build on iphone I found errors
[image: errors][image: errors]

I try to update all nugget but not working ,Linker behavior :Link Framework sdks only ,supported architecture:Armv7+Arm64 ,Deployment traget:9.0

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you provided, there are two reasons.

**For Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class:** You can add the **[Protocol]** attribute to the api that binds the Objective-C protocol for annotation, you can refer to the official [Xamarin.iOS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt5210-native-linking-failed-undefined-symbol--please-verify-that-all-the-necessary-frameworks-have-been-referenced-and-native-libraries-are-properly-linked-in:%7E:text=MT5211%3A%20Native%20linking%20failed%2C%20undefined%20Objective%2DC%20class%3A%20*.%20The%20symbol%20%27*%27%20could%20not%20be%20found%20in%20any%20of%20the%20libraries%20or%20frameworks%20linked%20with%20your%20application.).

**For Native linking failed, undefined symbol:** A third-party binding requires a framework, but the binding does not specify this in its **[LinkWith]** attribute, you should modify the binding's [LinkWith] attribute, you can refer to the official [Xamarin.iOS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt5210-native-linking-failed-undefined-symbol--please-verify-that-all-the-necessary-frameworks-have-been-referenced-and-native-libraries-are-properly-linked-in:%7E:text=MT5210%3A%20Native%20linking%20failed%2C%20undefined%20symbol%3A%20*.%20Please%20verify%20that%20all%20the%20necessary%20frameworks%20have%20been%20referenced%20and%20native%20libraries%20are%20properly%20linked%20in.) for details.

Comment: [Protocol] where to add this please?

Comment: In the interface of binding bound an Objective-C protocol, you can refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors#mt5211-native-linking-failed-undefined-objective-c-class--the-symbol--could-not-be-found-in-any-of-the-libraries-or-frameworks-linked-with-your-application